# How to set up an updatable view with a join in Firebird?

Tags: sql, firebird

I've got three tables, let's call them `GRANDPARENT`, `PARENT` and `CHILD`.  `PARENT` has a FK column to `GRANDPARENT`'s PK, and `CHILD` has a FK column to `PARENT`'s PK.  So far, so good.

Now I want to set up a view that contains all the information in `CHILD`, plus the PK from `GRANDPARENT`.  So:

```
CREATE VIEW CHILD_VIEW
(
  ID,
  PARENT_ID,
  OTHER_STUFF,
  GRANDPARENT_ID
)
AS
SELECT 
  C.ID,
  C.PARENT_ID,
  C.OTHER_STUFF,
  C.GRANDPARENT_ID
FROM CHILD C
join PARENT P on P.ID = C.PARENT_ID;
```

Not too hard.  But here's the tricky part: I want to be able to `INSERT` or `UPDATE` to this view, and have all relevant data get written to the `CHILD` table, and the `GRANDPARENT_ID` value, if any, should be ignored.

I've done some Googling around and apparently it should be possible to set up an updatable view like this "by using triggers," but it doesn't explain anywhere what I'm supposed to do with the triggers to achieve this effect.  I think I know more or less how to handle the `INSERT` case, but what about the `UPDATE` case?  `UPDATE` statements have `WHERE` clauses, and can contain or not contain any arbitrary column(s) in the table.

For example, how do I use a trigger to transform something like `update CHILD_VIEW set (blah blah blah) where ID = 5` into `update CHILD set (blah blah blah excluding GRANDPARENT_ID) where ID = 5`?

Comment: Good question about the `UPDATE` of only some columns... AFAIK there is no way to detect which columns are included in the `UPDATE` statement which caused the `ON UPDATE` trigger to fire. I think this is worth a feature request in Firebird tracker, if there isn't already one.

Comment: Shouldn't in your code `C.GRANDPARENT_ID` be `P.GRANDPARENT_ID`?

Comment: no multiple table view `INSERT`/`UPDATE`s?  booooo!

Answer (score 6):

Well, you do it by using triggers, as you already found out :)

It really is that simple, you can use all the features available in triggers (ie `OLD` and `NEW` contexts)... if you're using Firebird 2.1 or newer then you can use the [UPDATE OR INSERT](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-update-or-insert.html) statement, or you can use the [INSERTING](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-inserting.html) and [UPDATING](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-updating.html) context variables to detect is it update or insert in multi-action trigger. Or, of course, you can write separate `ON UPDATE` and `ON INSERT` triggers...

So your trigger might look something like this

```
CREATE TRIGGER CHILD_VIEW_Save FOR CHILD_VIEW
ACTIVE BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE POSITION 10
AS
BEGIN
  IF(NEW.ID IS NULL)THEN NEW.ID = GEN_ID(GEN_Child, 1);
  UPDATE OR INSERT INTO CHILD (ID, PARENT_ID, OTHER_STUFF, GRANDPARENT_ID)
            VALUES(NEW.ID, NEW.PARENT_ID, NEW.OTHER_STUFF, NEW.GRANDPARENT_ID);
END
```

Comment: ...and what about the WHERE clause when it's an `UPDATE`?

Comment: What about it? If you mean the `where` in the `UPDATE CHILD_View WHERE` then you don't care about it in the trigger (trigger will be fired for each matching row), if you mean the `WHERE` "inside the trigger" then either use the `UPDATE OR INSERT` or write the WHERE clause yourself (you know the PK of the table you're about to update inside the trigger).

Comment: OK, good point on the PK.  The other tricky thing is an `UPDATE` that does not update the entire column set.  If I have 5 columns in the table, and the UPDATE statement only sets 3 of them, what will a blanket trigger like your example do to the other two columns?

Comment: Off the top of my head (ie without testing) the fields not included in the update would have the NEW context NULL. So if partial updates are allowed you probably want to read the existing record first, then use NEW.fld IS NULL to detect unchanged fields and build an update statement that way... this might be a problem when you need to set some field to NULL though... AFAIK there is no way to get list of fields included in the UPDATE statement inside ON UPDATE trigger.